# PHP - Validate integer with filter_var() function

Tags: php, function, boolean

I see everywhere on the web that I should write something like this if I want to use the filter_var() function to validate an integer:

```
if (filter_var($int, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false){
    echo 'Integer ok';
}else{
    echo 'Not an integer';
}
```

From what I know, the expression filter_var($int, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) return false if the content of $int is not evaluated as an integer or return the integer inside $int.

As any integer is then evaluated is true by the PHP (except for 0 of course), I would like to know the concrete difference when doing this:

```
if (filter_var($int, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false)
```

Or this:

```
if (filter_var($int, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) == true)
```

For which values do these 2 expressions send different results?

I also have another question: if my variable $int contains the boolean true, in any case the result will be 'Integer ok' it seems. Are we obliged to isolate this case? Because everyone talks a lot about the "number begin by 0" case but not about this one...

Thank you!

Edit: Please do not suggest me to use other methods to validate an integer, I do not want to use other methods. As a matter of facts, I want to learn how PHP really works in depth. That is why I am wondering on this case of always seeing "!==false" and never simply "==true"

Comment: Returns the filtered data, or FALSE if the filter fails. 
The best idea is to make .. (=== false) {} else {}

Comment: Depends if you want to check if it's FALSE first, or TRUE first. Take your pick.

Comment: Could just use `is_numeric`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: Unfortunately, none of you is answering me...

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `ctype_digit()`, try this:

```
if (!ctype_digit($int)) {
    echo 'Not an integer';
} else {
     echo 'Integer ok';
}
```

Comment: @PierreGiraud What do you want exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that checking for false will still work when the integer is 0, as you already pointed out, whereas checking for true you would then have to make an additional check for 0.

A boolean value of true will return as a valid int with a value of 1, as noted in [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php#119528) on the PHP manual page for the filters.

You can easily test this for yourself by printing out the results of various values passed through the filter.